# fminsearch for non linear regression Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, non-linear-regression, fminsearch

Can anyone explain to me how I can apply `fminsearch` to this equation to find the value of `K` (Diode Equality Factor) using the Matlab command window.

```
I = 10^-9(exp(38.68V/k)-1)
```

[image: Equation]

I have data values as follows:

```
Voltage := [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]:
Current:= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0.92, 12.02, 158.29]:
```

I used `fminsearch` and an error message appeared:

> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in @(k)sum((I(:)-Imodel(V(:),k)).^2)
>
> Error in fminsearch (line 189)
>   fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

I used this `fminsearch` code:

```
V = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0];
I = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07 ,0.92 ,12.02 ,158.29];
Imodel = @(V,k) 1E-9*(exp(38.68*V/k)-1);
k0 = 1;
kmodel = fminsearch(@(k) sum((I(:)-Imodel(V(:),k)).^2), k0)
```

Please explain what the problem in this code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are carrying on from this post: [Fminsearch Matlab (Non Linear Regression )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361989/fminsearch-matlab-non-linear-regression).  The linked post is trying to find the right coefficient `k` in your equation that minimizes the sum of squared errors between the input, which is predicted current from the current-voltage relation of a diode and the output, which is the measured current from a diode.  This current post is simply trying to get that off the ground.

In any case, this is a very simple error.  You're missing an element in your current array `I`.  It's missing one 0.  You can verify this by using `numel` on both `V` and `I`. Basically, `V` and `I` don't match in size. `numel(V) == 11` and `numel(I) == 10`.

The definition you have at the top of your question compared to how you defined your error, it's missing one final zero:

```
I = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.07, 0.92, 12.02, 158.29];
%//                    ^
```

When I run the code with this new `I`, I get:

```
>> kmodel

kmodel =

    1.4999
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you have resolved my problem.